# How do I reconfigure the transmitter for Powering Up?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm at the Diamond City Radio Station and have been tasked with reconfiguring the transmitter using parts that are on site. I've found the parts in a crate and I have three of them:

- the thing with the dials
- the thing with the tubes
- the thing with the buttons

[image: the transmitter]

I've tried these a variety of ways so far but with limited success. How do I reconfigure the transmitter for Powering Up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the array of green lights along the top of the middle machine. There are three unlit and one will light up for each component you put in the correct unit.

[image: completed reconfiguring]

The thing with the buttons goes into the unit on the left, the thing with the dials goes in the unit in the middle and the thing with the tubes goes in the unit on the right.